# =VLOOKUP(SUMIFS) Statement requires long processing time

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, sumifs

**EDIT**

Workable File: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IhxKqnj62vssttZA73hF-S_TvynQNPdtSyb7wWq3Kpo/edit?usp=sharing

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVe16.png

**OBJECTIVE**

I am currently creating a pricing model for CUSTOMERS, who order specific PRODUCTS, and CONFIGURATIONS of said product. The end result is to SUM SALES and LOOKUP a table to place the customer into a category.

**APPROACH**

- 500,000+ Rows of data
- SUMIF: Sum Range = SALES; Criteria = (CUSTOMER
  ID, PRODUCT ID, CONFIGURATION)
- VLOOKUP: Take SUMIF value and
  partially match to PRICING TIER table, return Pricing Tier (e.g
  "Silver Tier", "Gold Tier", "Platinum Tier")
- Once pricing tiers have been defined, create a pivot table for easy filtering

**PROBLEM(S)**:
Processing time for rows is 30-60 minutes. I've tried breaking out the SUMIFS statements from the VLOOKUP to calculate them independently, but had no measurable success. I've also tried making SQL queries to the server (using DSUM) to reduce the local workload, but this also had no positive effect in processing time.

**QUESTIONS**

1. How can I efficiently process large amounts of information and properly categorize CUSTOMERS based off of their SALES, PRODUCT ID, and CONFIGURATION criteria?
2. I've been considering doing this in VBA, but am not sure whether or not VBA is actually more efficient than a cell formula.
3. Would add-in utilities offer any solution (e.g power pivot or power query)?

Comment: With 500,000 rows of data, array formulas are not the way to go.  VBA would probably be best.  But it is very difficult to give you a more specific answer without seeing a sample of the data, the expected outcome and the actual formula that is currently working.

Comment: Noted. Would a file upload be preferred, or would a screenshot suffice?

Comment: Preferably a mock up of the data as text, barring that a screenshot.

Comment: @ScottCraner: please see attached: Workable File: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IhxKqnj62vssttZA73hF-S_TvynQNPdtSyb7wWq3Kpo/edit?usp=sharing

Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/d25R8lc.png

Comment: My guess is you have other formulas in the table that are causing the time.  Even with 500,000 data points, this should not take 30 minutes to calculate.

Comment: I can confirm that the VLOOKUP(SUMIF) statement is the only formula in the workbook

Answer (score 2):

With 500 thousand rows I would consider using Access or another database application. It's just a lot of data for VLOOKUPs and SUMIFs and even Excel VBA is going to be slow if you do tons of comparisons.

SUMIFs and VLOOKUPs are very easy to replicate in queries, and will be much much faster.

If using ACCESS, try using this SQL Query:

```
SELECT [Customer ID],[Product ID],[Configuration],[Pricing Tier] 
FROM 

    (SELECT [Data Table].[Customer ID], [Data Table].[Product ID], 
    [Data Table].[Configuration], Sum([Data Table].Sales) AS [Sales Sum]
    FROM [Data Table]
    GROUP BY [Data Table].[Customer ID], [Data Table].[Product ID], 
    [Data Table].[Configuration])

AS T,
[Pricing Table] P
WHERE [Annual Sales] = (SELECT Max([Annual Sales]) 
                       FROM [Pricing Table] 
                       WHERE [Annual Sales] <= [Sales Sum]);
```

This should (hopefully) do the trick. Let me know!

Comment: I had created a query in MS Access using DSUM, but the process took much longer:


`'Pricing Tier: DSUM("[Sales]","[SalesTable]","[Pricing Tier]=' " & [CustomerID] & ' " AND [ProductID]=&[ProductID] AND [Configuration]=&Configuration"'")`


Obviously this was done in the Query Wizard and not SQL directly ;)

Comment: Hmm... do you happen to still have the query? If so, could you post the SQL?

Comment: Unfortunately I've since removed the query as it was way too slow. I suppose I'll look into creating my own SQL query

Comment: I just added an SQL query that I believe will help. Give it a try and let me know. (In this case I used pricing table as the table with tiers and data table as the table you use with the other information. Column headers I kept constant, but double check them.